# Writing Linear Transformations as Matrices in Terms of the Standard Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm unsure if I completely understand this concept and would appreciate some feedback on my working. Is the following a correct way to write a linear transformation as a matrix in terms of the standard basis? Are my workings correct? If there's anything that's incorrect, please elaborate as to why and provide step-by-step reasoning. :)

> $$
> \begin{align}
> & f_3:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3 \\
> & \qquad(x,y,z)\mapsto(-y,x,z) \\
> \\
> & f(\vec{e}_1) = (0,1,0) \\
> & f(\vec{e}_2) = (-1,0,0) \\
> & f(\vec{e}_3) = (0,0,1) \\
> \\
> \vec{e}_1&\mapsto
> \overset{\displaystyle A}{\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & -1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0  & 0 \\
> 0 & 0  & 1
> \end{bmatrix}}
> \overset{\displaystyle \vec{x}}{\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 0 \\
> 0
> \end{bmatrix}}
> =f(\vec{e}_1)=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 \\
> 1 \\
> 0
> \end{bmatrix}
> \\ \\ 
> \vec{e}_2&\mapsto
> \overset{\displaystyle A}{\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & -1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0  & 0 \\
> 0 & 0  & 1
> \end{bmatrix}}
> \overset{\displaystyle \vec{x}}{\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 \\
> 1 \\
> 0
> \end{bmatrix}}
> =f(\vec{e}_2)=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> -1 \\
> 0 \\
> 0
> \end{bmatrix}
> \\ \\
> \vec{e}_3&\mapsto
> \overset{\displaystyle A}{\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & -1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0  & 0 \\
> 0 & 0  & 1
> \end{bmatrix}}
> \overset{\displaystyle \vec{x}}{\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 \\
> 0 \\
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}}
> =f(\vec{e}_3)=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 \\
> 0 \\
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}
> \\ \\
> A_{55}&=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & -1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0  & 0 \\
> 0 & 0  & 1
> \end{bmatrix}\ \ \Huge\color{lightgreen}{\checkmark}
> \end{align}
> $$

The green tick is indicating that my final answer is correct, but I'm unsure of my reasoning and workings.

Thank you!

Comment: Perfect. Your working is correct, you are pointing in the right direction for now.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is correct but I think you overworked. I think it is easier if done directly as follows: since each and every $\;f(e_i)\;$ must be written as a linear combination wrt the same standard basis, directly write:

$$\begin{align*}&f(e_1)=(0,1,0)=&0\cdot(1,0,0)+1\cdot(0,1,0)+0\cdot(0,0,1)\\
&f(e_2)=(-1,0,0)=&-1\cdot(1,0,0)+0\cdot(0,1,0)+0\cdot(0,0,1)\\
&f(e_3)=(0,0,1)=&0\cdot(1,0,0)+0\cdot(0,1,0)+1\cdot(0,0,1)&\end{align*}$$

Now take **the transpose** of the coefficients matrix above, and *that* is your matrix.

Observe that working with the standard matrix is very simple: already from the very first part, where you evaluate $\;f(e_1),...,f(e_3)\;$ , all you have to do is to take the right side, make it into a matrix and take the transpose...and that's all! What I did above is to show you the general way, when things aren't as trivial.

Comment: That's it. You can use this method once you are more familiar with things.

Comment: Is $f(e_2)$ supposed to be $-1 * (1,0,0)$ ?

Comment: @ThePointer Of course. Thanks for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your work is correct.

In general, just from linearity, a linear transformation $T$ is defined if, for any basis $\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n\}$ we know the transformed vectors $\{T(u_1),T(u_2),\cdots,T(u_n)\}$.

If $\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n\}$ is the standard basis this gives that the matrix representing $T$ has as columns exactly the vectors $ \{T(u_1),T(u_2),\cdots,T(u_n)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually understand what you are trying to achieve. I think you contradict yourself in the first rows if I understand correctly.

Do you want to describe the linear transformation which maps $(x, y, z)$ base vectors to $(-y, x, z)$ vectors?

If YES then since you know the transformed vectors of the original basis vectors, all you have to do is construct the 3 by 3 matrix (since you are working in  $\mathbb{R}^3$ and want to describe a linear transformation in this space, so you will still stay in the same space) which contains the transformed vectors of the original base vectors IN ORDER!

So if you want this:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\-1\\0
\end{bmatrix} $

$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix} $

$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix} $

...you just have to construct this matrix as the transformation matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: That matrix would be the correct one **if** the world would use what algebraists used to do mostly until some 40-50 years ago, namely: to apply the function *from the right*, say something like $\;(x)f\,,\,vT\;$ , etc., instead of the widely used notation nowadays: $\;f(x),\,Tv\;$ , etc. For the latter, which almost everyone uses now in linear algebra and most other parts of mathematics, we need **the transpose** of that last matrix you wrote.

Comment: I know that, my confusion comes from that he says this at the beggining: $(x, y, z) \mapsto (-y, x, z)$ and after that he says $x \mapsto y$ and $y \mapsto -x$ and $z \mapsto z$. Btw $x$ should be $\vec{i}$, $y$ should be $\vec{j}$ and $z$ should be $\vec{k}$...

Comment: That notation with $\;i,j,k\;$ is more used among physicists, not so much by mathematicians.